# Нужна ли запятая после союза И?

Tags: пунктуация

В соответствии с Методическими рекомендациями по передаче 
в безвозмездное пользование федерального имущества, составляющего государственную казну Российской Федерации, направленными письмом Росимущества от 05.07.2013 № ИБ-07/30284, и учитывая отсутствие необходимых документов, Росимущество готово рассмотреть данное обращение после предоставления в адрес Росимущества пакета документов, необходимого для принятия решения по вышеуказанному вопросу в установленном порядке.

Answer (score 1):

**В соответствии с Методическими рекомендациями** по передаче в безвозмездное пользование федерального **имущества, составляющего** государственную казну Российской Федерации, **направленными** письмом Росимущества от 05.07.2013 № ИБ-07/30284, **и учитывая отсутствие необходимых документов,** Росимущество готово рассмотреть данное обращение после предоставления в адрес Росимущества пакета документов, необходимого для принятия решения по вышеуказанному вопросу в установленном порядке.

Запятая после И не нужна, так как союз И связывает два обстоятельственных оборота: оборот на основе существительного и деепричастный обоот

Answer (score 1):

> В соответствии с Методическими рекомендациями по передаче в
>   безвозмездное пользование федерального имущества, составляющего
>   государственную казну Российской Федерации, **направленными письмом**
>   **Росимущества от 05.07.2013 № ИБ-07/30284**, и учитывая отсутствие
>   необходимых документов, Росимущество готово рассмотреть данное
>   обращение после предоставления в адрес Росимущества пакета документов,
>   необходимого для принятия решения по вышеуказанному вопросу в
>   установленном порядке.

Предложение проще будет читаться, если его несколько перекомпоновать:

> *В соответствии с **направленными письмом Росимущества от 05.07.2013 № ИБ-07/30284** Методическими рекомендациями по передаче в безвозмездное
>   пользование федерального имущества, составляющего государственную
>   казну Российской Федерации,  и учитывая отсутствие необходимых
>   документов, Росимущество готово рассмотреть данное обращение после
>   предоставления в адрес Росимущества пакета документов, необходимого
>   для принятия решения по вышеуказанному вопросу в установленном
>   порядке.*

.

Но это лишь минимальная правка... Более существенную предложить пока не могу, т. к. не знаю ни содержания письма *№ ИБ-07/30284 от 05.07.2013*, ни того, о каком *пакете документов* идёт речь.

Answer (score 0):

Я не профессионал, но позволю себе выразить свое мнение (может, окажется полезным). По-моему, запятая после И не нужна, потому что деепричастный оборот не обособляется, если выступает в качестве однородного члена предложения с необособленным обстоятельством. (см: [Обособление деепричастного оборота | orfogrammka.ru](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/)). Может возникнуть вопрос: если деепричастный оборот не обособляется, то почему стоит запятая перед "Росимущество". Тот же источник дает ответ: для смыслового выделения или попутного пояснения сочетания наречия с одиночным деепричастием или с деепричастным оборотом могут обособляться: **Тихо и как бы капельку побледнев, проговорила Катерина Ивановна (Дост.)** 
Конечно, "в соответствии с" - не наречие, но тоже обстоятельство образа действия, так что этот подход вполне применим в нашем случае. Таким образом, получаем:

**В соответствии с ... и учитывая …, Росимущество готово рассмотреть ...**